# How can I display the footcites in 2 columns?

Tags: citing, footnotes, jurabib

I saw some PDF-files, where citations are shown in the footnotes in 2 columns.

I use the `jurabib` package. Is this possible there, too? I don't know, wether the PDF files are coded with LaTeX or not.

I use the `\foocite` to cite some text in my seminar work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you gave no MWE I can not test if it compiles with your code.

The one possibility I knew is to add

```
\usepackage{dblfnote}
```

to your preamble (before `\begin{document}`). This packages sets footnotes with double columns.  You can read the documentation with `texdoc dblfnote` from console/terminal.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am new to this forum (and pretty new to LaTeX). Your solution did exactly what I needed. Thanks! :)